# Where are the save game of Temple Run 2 Blazing Sands located?

Tags: temple-run-2

I'm going to reset my smartphone but I don't want to lose all the progress I've made in Temple Run 2 Blazing Sands. Please tell me where is the save file located? I want to backup everything in the game I've achieved. After resetting my smartphone I'll install every app freshly.

**UPDATE**: I'm having an Android Smartphone.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I just switched from a Galaxy S4 to a Galaxy S7. I have the game fully beat on the S4 with all upgrades and global challenge prizes. On the S7 it wants me to start from scratch. I copied the entire Android/data/com.imangi.templerun2 folder with all of the contents and it doesn't work. If I can't figure out how to get my progress back I'm just deleting the game as I'm not starting from scratch. I do have "Google Play Games" installed on both devices and it works on both devices, but the S7 copy is not updating with any kind of progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Android, the location depends on where the game is located (SD card or phone's internal memory).

To check if your app is on the SD card (if you have one) or in the phone's memory, simply go through Settings/Applications, and you'll be able to see where the game is located (you also have the possibility to move the app to your convenience).

Then, use your phone's File Explorer or go in the Play Store to find one ([File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx)).

Once you're in the explorer, go to Android/data (whether SD card or phone memory), and you will see many folders like **com.xxx.xxx**. Find the one with Temple Run 2 in the name (can't remember the folder's name), open that folder and you'll find the files you're looking for.

**NOTE:**

If you linked your Google Play Games account with the game, logically your progress would be saved in your google account. So a factory reset shouldn't make you lose your progress. You'll just have to re-link with Play Games once you reinstall the app.

**EDIT:**

I suggest you copy the whole game folder on to a USB drive or on your computer before the factory reset. I'm not 100% sure that all the progress is saved on the GPG account, so it's safer in my opinion.

Comment: Any information in case it's an iPhone, or the tiniest chance it's a Windows phone?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone, I just have an Android... so I don't have any idea for both iPhone and WPhone :/

Comment: Its Android. I don't have SD card. I found the folder 'com.imangi.templerun2', in that folder there were two folders - 'cache' and 'files', 'files' folder was empty, 'cache' folder was having another folder in which there were two video ads file (.mp4). That's all, nothing else was there. I think the save game isn't there. But I've connected the game with Google play games account. But whenever I'm not connected to internet, how it would be loading and saving progress?